# users joined group count in buddypress

Tags: user-meta, buddypress

How to get users already joined group count by user-id or username in BuddyPress.

For example,

In the member listing page, in the members loop, I like to get users group count and display in the grid.

Answer (score 0):

To get the group count, use `groups_get_user_groups`.
Find it in: `buddypress\bp-groups\bp-groups-functions.php`

In the members loop, the member id is provided via: `bp_member_user_id()`

You will need to check the member-loop template to find out how to hook into the loop. Or overload that template in your child theme and add a `do_action` wherever you want it.

Once you have a hook, use it to call something like this:

```
function get_group_count_for_member() { 

    $groups_for_member = groups_get_user_groups( bp_member_user_id() );

    echo 'Groups: ' . $groups_for_member['total'];

}
```